# Java.util.Scanner Error

Tags: java

I am writing a program to return the future value based off some input the user gives

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import utility package, scanner class
import java.lang.Math; //import language package, math class 
class InvestmentCalculation

{
   public static void main(String[] args) 

   {

      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

      //Principle Value Input
      System.out.print("Enter principle deposit: ");
      int p = s.nextInt ();

      //Interest Rate Input
      System.out.print("Enter annual interest rate: ");
      int r = s.nextInt ();

      double fv = p * Math.pow( (1.0 + r/100), 10);  


      //operation print
      System.out.println("Your investment will be worth: " + fv);
   }
}
```

When I run the program, after I type in the rate it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at InvestmentCalculation.main(Addition.java:20)
```

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: It seems you have pressed enter after the first input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are probably entering the rate as a double and the input is thus incorrect.

NOTE: The `InputMismatchException` in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) reads as follows:

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

Fix via:

```
//Interest Rate Input
System.out.print("Enter annual interest rate: ");
double r = s.nextDouble();
```

Comment: No problem. And just to extend the limits of your program, you may want to change the principal deposit to a double type as well.